# Reemplazar icono en un Jframe

Tags: java

Como hago para quitar el icono (la taza de café) en un Jframe de Java.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

Debes crear un `ImageIcon`:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(pathDelIcon);
```

Luego lo seteas en tu JFrame con [`setIconImage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage-java.awt.Image-):

```
objetoJFrame.setIconImage(img.getImage());
```

---

Si tu imagen es un recurso:

```
objetoJFrame.setIconImage(
 Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
   getClass().getResource(pathDelIconResource)
 )
);
```